# Who can explain this poem?

Tags: meaning

I want to know whats the meaning of part 2
Afterp( the perceiving...)

Four a.m. in the Woods

> Darkness softens, a thin 
>   tissue of mist between trees.
>   One by one the day's
>   uncountable voices come out
>   like twilight fireflies, like stars.
>   The perceiving self sits
>   with his back against rough bark,
>   casting ten thousand questions into the future.
>   As shadows take shape, the curtains part
>   for the length of time it takes to gasp,
>   and behold, the purpose of his
>   life dawns on him.

Comment: This question would appear to be off-topic on ELU, as it deals with “Criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature”, which is [out of scope for the site](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Yes I know. I just want to know its structure in simple english

Comment: If there is anything particular that you do not understand, or where you cannot understand how the sentence is structured, please highlight those bits and let us know what it is you do not understand about them; otherwise, you are asking for something that this site is not intended to provide answers for.

Comment: I'm writing by my phone cause of this I am not able to highlight but I really need your help. I want to know,as I said, about structure of second part of poem and its meaning.i mean after (( the perceiving self...)) till end.

Comment: You can highlight words by enclosing them in either asterisks (`*`) or underscores (`_`)—one to make it italic, two to make it bold, three to make it bold italic. Simply asking what the structure and meaning of a six-line piece of a poem is, is off-topic and as such will (should) not be answered.

Comment: I would take a literal meaning thus: "He sits with his back against a tree, asking himself ten thousand questions about the day's events (uncountable voices) and what they mean for the future. Shadows take shape amongst the trees but as the mists part like a curtain for a short time, the purpose of his life suddenly becomes clearer." However, this being poetry, you can interpret shadows/mist/parting curtains as things going on his mind rather than the physical world.

Comment: The poem is about George Washington Carver. I think it represents him being outside and having a bolt of inspiration. It comes from a long list of poems that Marilyn Nelson wrote to describe his life.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to know who is (perceiving ) and what is meaning of ( it takes to gasp ) and so on...

Comment: And I really thank academi to let my question be here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The perceiving self" is the author of the poem, or more generally, one who is self-aware. He is sitting against a tree's rough bark and wondering about the future ("casting ten thousand questions"). The curtains part in an instant (the length of time it "takes to gasp"). (Curtains are probably the "tissue of mist," which are darkness described in lines 1 and 2.)

He achieves clarity as to the "purpose of his life"; the darkness ends and a new day is dawning. (A metaphoric dawn, as the true sunrise is probably several hours away from four a.m.)